I tried to transform the transfer component of the ANT DESIGN framework into a component that supports single selection
In the callback function of api onchange provided to the transfer, I tried to control the data rendered on the page by manipulating the array provided to api targetKeys. but did not take effect
Here is the function I provided to the onchange:
  const onChange = (nextTargetKeys) => {
    if (nextTargetKeys.length > 1) {
      const lastSelectedKey = nextTargetKeys[nextTargetKeys.length - 1];
      setTargetKeys([lastSelectedKey]);
    } else {
      setTargetKeys(nextTargetKeys);
    }
  };

Here is the function I provided to the onselectChange:
  const onSelectChange = (sourceSelectedKeys: string[], targetSelectedKeys: string[]) => {
    console.log(sourceSelectedKeys);
    console.log(targetSelectedKeys);
    if (enableSelectAll) {
      setSelectedKeys([...sourceSelectedKeys, ...targetSelectedKeys]);
    } else {
      const allSelectedKeys = [...sourceSelectedKeys, ...targetSelectedKeys];
      if (allSelectedKeys.length > 1) {
        console.log(allSelectedKeys);
        if (targetSelectedKeys.length > 0) {
          setSelectedKeys([sourceSelectedKeys[sourceSelectedKeys.length-1]]);
        } else {
          setSelectedKeys([allSelectedKeys[allSelectedKeys.length - 1]]);
        }
      } else {
        setSelectedKeys(allSelectedKeys);
      }
    }
  };

Here is my component:
 <Transfer
   dataSource={data}
   titles={['Source', 'Target']}
   listStyle={{ width: 250, height: 340 }}
   targetKeys={targetKeys}
   selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
   onSelectChange={onSelectChange}
   onChange={onChange}
   render={renderItem}
   showSelectAll={enableSelectAll}
 />

In my opinion, there is only one object in the targetKeys that should be rendered to the target column on the right, but as I move data to the target column, the target column on the right is also increasing data.

My Transfer component is wrapped by the Form form, so what I need to do is modify the TargetKeys inside the persons provided in the Form form instead of modifying the TargetKeys provided to the TransFer component.Here is my full form code :
    <Form scrollToFirstError layout="vertical" form={form} onFinish={onSubmit}>
      <Form.Item name="persons" valuePropName="targetKeys" label={_(msg`转办人员`)} rules={[{ required: true }]}>
        <Transfer
          dataSource={mockData}
          titles={['Source', 'Target']}
          listStyle={{ width: 250, height: 340 }}
          onChange={onChange}
          render={(item) => `${item.title}`}
          showSelectAll={enableSelectAll}
        />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>

This is the modified onChange method
  const onChange = (nextTargetKeys: any) => {
    if (nextTargetKeys.length > 1) {
      form.setFieldsValue({ persons: nextTargetKeys[0] });
    } else {
      form.setFieldsValue({ persons: nextTargetKeys });
    }
  };

